# Scope in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

i've called a view (menuview) passing it a var (prova)but from view called it results undefined(console.log(this.model),in menuview). Can anybody help me in finding errors?

ROUTER

```
      home: function() {
      new BarraScreamView();
      new MenuView();
       var self=this;


      var amicizie= new Amicizie();
      amicizie.fetch({
      success: function(object) {
     console.log(object);
     var prova=object.where({invitante: Parse.User.current().id,conferma:0});//mettere      
      invitato
     var num=prova.length;

     new MenuView({model:prova});<<<---------

     },
     error: function(amici, error) {

    }
    });
```

MENUVIEW

```
       var MenuView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("#menu_container"),

    events: {

    },

    template: Handlebars.compile(template),

    initialize: function () {
        console.log(this.model);<<<------------


    this.render();
        console.log("menuview");

    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is quite simple..

There 2 places where you seem to be creating a new Instance of `MenuView()`

```
 home: function () {
     new BarraScreamView();
     new MenuView();     <----- First Instance here
     var self = this;
     var amicizie = new Amicizie();
     amicizie.fetch({
         success: function (object) {
             new MenuView({       <----- Second Instance here     
                 model: prova
             });
```

The views are initialized in the order in which they are loaded. When you create a new View using

`new MenuView();` It will hit the initialize method of the view

```
 initialize: function () {
        console.log(this.model);<<<------------
 }                   ^    ^
                     |    ------ Corresponds to the model passed in
                                 But there is nothing passed here
          corresponds to the view
```

So it logs undefined in the first case.

Comment: perfect,problem solved. There is an other problem: in router if i use prova.length works perfectly,but if i use length on this.model (this.model.length) in menuview appear this error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Right.. It will again call the first Instance which is `new MenuView()` where in no model is passed... So it will log `undefined` for `this.model` .. So obviously it will throw an error when you try to do `undefined.length`  .. Try replacing `console.log(this.model.length)` with `console.log(this.model && this.model.length)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a guess here...

You are creating a new menu view with `new MenuView();` in your `home` method before you call the `amicizie.fetch` method. My guess is that your `undefined` from `console.log(this.model)` is 
from *that* view. Are you sure that isn't the case?

Try commenting out that view and put a `console.log('error')` in your `amicizie.fetch` error handler to make sure that there are no errors in fetching the model.